# Xcode Storyboard Preview doesn't show Background Color added by code

Tags: ios, swift

I changed the background color of **View** to a dark grey color in ViewController.swift and this shows up in the simulator but in the storyboard the **View** has a white background. Is there a way to refresh/force the storyboard to show the right background color.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:84.0/255.0, green:84.0/255.0, blue:84.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)
```

Comment: storyboard does not care much about your code. You can try playing around with IBInspectable and IDesignable. But other than that your requirement does not make any sense.

Comment: @luk2302. Thanks for the suggestion. Just wanted to confirm if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have black for example instead of white in the storyboard, you can do something like this:

**1.Create class ColorBlockView that will be @IBDesignable**

```
@IBDesignable class ColorBlockView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var blockColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet{
            backgroundColor = blockColor
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Then in Identity inspector choose ColorBlockView for the view that you want to change the background color**

[image]

**3. Choose whatever color you want to have as a background**

[image]

**4. If it didn’t show the color, Editor -> Refresh All Views**

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

xcode story board preview doesn't show exactly what will run in the app so unfortunately there is no way for your case But if you want to see you just need to change the color in story board or ignore that because the code will working

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I didn't find any solution to this on the net and just wanted to confirm if there was some hidden refresh option to make this happen. I understand the only option is to apply color via the Attribute Inspector.